# MYSQl, creating a record set combining data

Tags: mysql

Okei so i have 3 tables.

1 : User, 
2 : course,
3 : registration

the 3 table cointains a reference/foreign key to user and to course. What i wanna do is to create a record set/(select the data) of all the courses a user has registrer to. So i want to create a table the contains a list of the course name, teacher name and som other information thats in the course database based on 1 single user

Comment: So what do you need ? Do you need someone to code for you ? Try something first !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from course inner join registration on course.id = registration.course_id where registration.user_id = 1
```

This will give you all the courses a user with ID 1 is registered for. simple